# Create views from combination of various vocabularies' terms

Tags: views, search, nodes

I am trying to find out if there is a module that can work out this magic or if I need to make a custom solution.

The problem:
I have Vocabulary1, Vocabulary2, Vocabulary3. The ideal would be to have something like tagadelic for all 3 vocabularies on the side, so whenever a tag is clicked the content displayed is additionally filtered by that extra tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have nice block displaying all terms coming from your mentioned vocab by help of [Cumulus](https://drupal.org/project/cumulus).

Though its in DEV mode but it works fine. This requires module [Tagadelic](https://drupal.org/project/tagadelic) to be enabled first.

You can create a cumulus block by visiting `admin/structure/block/add-cumulus-block`, where you can mention name of the block & setting for it such as `Vocabulary IDs to be included`, `Number of tags to display`, `Width`, `Height` etc..